# Question of maximum pairwise product in python3 and when taking long input such as 100000 and 90000 and it returns 0

Tags: python-3.x, int, long-integer

I would like to take a long input and print the maximum pairwise product between them but i'm getting 0 as my output. e.g. would like to take 10^5 and 9^4 as my input and print maximum pairwise product 9^9 but i'm getting 0 as my answer. So how to solve this problem of taking long input in python3?

```
   n = len(numbers)
   largest = 0
   second = 0
   for i in range(0,n):
     if numbers[i] > largest:
       second = largest
       largest = numbers[i]
       
   max_product = largest * second
   return max_product

if __name__ == '__main__':
   input_numbers = []
   input_n = int(input())
   input_numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
   print(max_pairwise_product(input_numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some syntax erros in the main function about `input`, this should fix:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   input_numbers = []
   input_n = input()
   input_numbers = [int(x) for x in input_n.split()]
   print(max_pairwise_product(input_numbers))
```

About the logic, think about what will occurs if your is `3 2 1 0`. Since the max value will be replace in the first iteration, `second` will receive the current value of `largest` that is `0` and this will never be replaced with another one. To fix that you should first check if the value is bigger than the second one and only after that check if it bigger than `largest`. The following snippet should solve your problem:

```
def max_pairwise_product(numbers):
  n = len(numbers)
  largest = float('-inf')
  second = float('-inf')
  for i in range(0, n):
    if numbers[i] > second:
      if numbers[i] > largest:
        second = largest
        largest = numbers[i]
      else:
        second = numbers[i]
  
  max_product = largest * second
  return max_product
```

I also changed the values of `largest` and `second` to start if negative infinity.

Comment: Your code pass for long input and the input you gave but it fails for the input like 1 2 3. So, your code is not good for all type of input.

Comment: @YASHPRATAPSINGH I forgot `second = largest` in the inner if. Fixed. Thanks.